# Making changes to ActiveRecord instances I never want to commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am working on a Rails app with several model classes that extend ActiveRecord::Base. I've implemented a variety of methods on some of these model classes that can be used update the database contents, and these methods are all working as I want them to work. For example, I have a `TeamStats` class that stores various statistic values to the database and I've defined  methods that allow me to update those attributes by applying game results:

```
class TeamStats < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :team

  def << game_result
     # Lots of stuff here to update persisted attributes for 
     # wins, losses, total points scored, etc
  end

end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :stats, :class_name => TeamStats, :dependent => destroy
end
```

Now I find myself wanting to reuse that logic but with some temporary data that I don't ever want to commit to the database. For example, I want to recompute the statistics for a team using a subset of the games rather than all of them. So I have code that does something like this:

```
# relevant_game_results is an array containing game results I want considered
teams.each do |team|
    new_stats = TeamStats.new(:team => team)
    relevent_game_results.each do |results|
        new_stats << results
    end
end

# Do stuff to choose a team based on these un-persisted stats that have been 
# assigned to the team

# After I'm done, through all the team_stats I created and make sure all of the
# related team model objects still reference their original team stats values
```

My initial plan for this was to modify my model instances and then call `reload` on those instances when I'm done. For example:

```
teams.each do |team|
    team.reload
end
```

I think that will work, but I'll have to do it for lots of objects and I'd rather do this in one operation if I can.

It seems like what I really need is a transaction that always gets rolled back rather than being committed. What is the most appropriate "rails way" to do this? Am I supposed to do this within a `transaction` block and then raise an `ActiveRecord::Rollback` at the end of my block? In other words, something like this?

```
Team.transaction do

  teams.each do |team|
      new_stats = TeamStats.new(:team => team)
      relevent_game_results.each do |results|
          new_stats << results
      end
  end

  # Do stuff to choose a team based on these un-persisted stats that have been 
  # assigned to the team

  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
```

That seems a little "dirty" to me but that just be my Java background coming through ;)
Is there a cleaner approach that is more in line with the Rails way?

UPDATE: It turns out that wrapping this within a transaction and rolling back isn't only ugly, it seems very hard to make it work right. Because the method executing this code can itself be in another transaction and because some of the tendency of some changes to ActiveRecord relationship objects being auto-saved, I was having to jump through numerous hoops to make it even work.

I've gone with the approach of creating a new TeamStats object altogether and just never saving it, based on the suggestion in the accepted answer. Seems to work much better for me.

Comment: could you provide a stupid simple example of operations you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rolling back, why not make a copy, and then never save it? For example:

```
# in TeamStats

def hypothetically_add(games)
  copy = dup
  games.each {|game| copy << game }
  copy
end
```

Perhaps also adding games to a Stats object one at a time is not the right approach if you are generating statistics based on querying all your games for matches. It might be better to operate on the collection of games.

```
# in Team

def stats_from_games_where(*conditions)
  games.where(*conditions).reduce( Hash.new(0) ) do |stats, game|
    stats[:wins] += 1 if # we won
    ... 
  end
end
```

Comment: I've thought about making a copy as well... And in the end I might end up being forced to do that. The problem I have with making a copy is that the TeamStats copy would `belong_to` the same Team, which uses a `has_one` for it's relationship to its stats. So when I make a copy of the stats, wouldn't the associated team also be updated to point to the new (unsaved) stats? I could also make a copy of the team, but then I'm making it harder and harder to get back to what I need - A reference to the original Team object that has been chosen based on its stats.

Comment: Don't make it through the association. Just make a duplicate TeamStats object and manually assign the team_id. I don't think that overwrites it, but you'll have to check.

Comment: It turns out I didn't need to worry about that association after all. After thinking about your suggestion and referring to the documentation, I found it said "Assigning an object to a belongs_to association does not save the object, since the foreign key field belongs on the parent. It does not save the parent either." So I changed my code to make a copy and never save that copy, and everything works very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at something like ActiveAttr (https://github.com/cgriego/active_attr), or Virtus https://github.com/solnic/virtus. You'd create objects that are completely in memory. There's a good railscast on this too: http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr

Comment: The problem with this approach, I think, is that I'm not trying to work with in-memory objects most of the time. In most cases, I really WANT for these model changes to go to the database. It's just in certain situations where I want to do some manipulations that don't get committed.

Comment: Why not move the logic into a class responsible for calculating stats only then? It would then be responsible for updating TeamStats as required (or not as the case may be).

Comment: I've been thinking about that, but it seems like a lot of extra work. The logic involved sets several different attributes of self, so if I extracted that logic into its own class (or a module) then I would have to implement another set of classes with identical relationship attributes that don't extend ActiveRecord::Base. I really want to use all of the behavior given to me by ActiveRecord, I just wan't more control over whether or not my changes get saved or not.